# JQGrid - Pop up for edit/add buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jqgrid, popup

I'm working with JQGrid to manage some datas from database.
I have a column which serve to edit or add new data. When i click on these buttons i want to have a popup with a form with all the field necessary.

I think with a picture it will be more clear :

[Form pop-up model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DmW0.png)

So here the code of my grid :

```js
            if (gridCtrp.length) {
                gridCtrp.jqGrid({
                    url: "{{ url('/') }}/contreparties/projet/{{ $ID_PROJET }}",
                    mtype: "GET",
                    datatype: 'json',
                    colNames: ["ID","Famille","Libellé","Détail","Précision","Valorisation","Tranche Mini","Tranche Maxi"],
                    colModel: [
                        {name: "ID_CONTREPARTIE", sortable: false, align:"center", hidden: true},
                        {name: "LIBCOD", align: "center",width: 100},
                        {name: "LIBEL_CTRPRT",align: "center", sortable: false, width: 100},
                        {name: "DETAIL_CTRPRT",align:"center", width: 100},
                        {name: "PRECISION_TRCH",align:"center",width: 150},
                        {name: "CORRES_MONETAIRE",align:"center", width: 150},
                        {name: "NUM_MINI", align:"center", width: 100},
                        {name: "NUM_MAXI", align: "center", width: 150}
                    ],
                    loadtext: "Chargement...",
                    viewrecords: true,
                    emptyrecords: "Aucune contrepartie",
                    width: 850,
                    height: 300,
                    scrollerbar: true,
                    rowNum: 100,
                    sortable: true,
                    loadonce: true,
                    hidegrid: false,
                    multipleSearch: true,
                    shrinkToFit: false,
                    gridview: true,
                    autoencode: false,
                    gridComplete: function() { 
                        var ids = gridCtrp.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                        var tabData = gridCtrp.jqGrid('getRowData');
                        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                            var id = ids[i];
                            var updateButton = "<a id='editButtonCtrp' rel='popover' data-toggle='popover' title='Popover Header'><i class='fa fa-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
                            var deleteButton = "<a href='' title='Supprimer'><i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
                            gridCtrp.jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{NUM_MAXI: tabData[i].NUM_MAXI + ' ' +  updateButton + ' ' + deleteButton });
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

I have tried with Bootstrap 4 popover and JQuery-UI Dialog and nothing is working for me.... Also when i have noted that when i run `console.log($('a[rel=popover]'))` to recover all edit/add button where i want to implement popup, it return nothing...

Is there someone who have already implements something like that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code in gridComplete is missing the binding action to buttons - you should bind a action to it. Where is is this code and how you try to run it.

The code below is a very old but is working:

```
gridComplete: function() {
    var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
        var cl = ids[i];
        be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editRow('"+cl+"');\"  />"; 
        se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\"  />"; 
        ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
        jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se+ce});
    }
}
```

Moreover this is very old approach and to optimize your code I highly recommend you to use a custom formatter - this will speed you code 10 times.

For this purpose you will need to read some [docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#custom-formatter):